# How to extend jQuery's $.Deferred promise object with a "catch" method, working the same way as its "fail" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I want to create a wrapper of the jQuery's Deferred object extending its methods: "resolve" and "reject", and more importantly its promise's "then" and "fail" method. However, instead of using its "fail" method, I want to replace/rename it with a "catch" method and instead its "then" method, I want to replace it with let's say "thenNew".

I've been trying to make it like this so far:

```
function ObjectPromise () {
    this.instance = $.Deferred();
    this._promise = this.instance.promise;
}
```

Working methods:

```
ObjectPromise.prototype.resolve = function ( data ) {
    this.instance.resolve(data);
}

ObjectPromise.prototype.reject = function ( data ) {
    this.instance.reject(data);
}
```

Not working methods ('catch' and 'thenNew'):

```
ObjectPromise.prototype.promise = function () {
    this.prom = this._promise()

    this.prom.thenNew = this.prom.then;
    this.prom.catch   = this.prom.fail;

    return this.prom;
}
```

So that when I have the following function:

```
function getUsersFromDb () {
    var deferred = new ObjectPromise();

    setTimeout( function () {
        deferred.resolve( 'data_resolved' );
    }, 2000 );

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

And then execute it, I'd like to have the following chain:

```
    getUsersFromDb().thenNew( function () { .... })
.thenNew( function () {
    var deferred = new ObjectPromise();

    setTimeout( function () {
        deferred.reject( 'data_rejected' );
    }, 2000 );

    return deferred.promise();
} ).thenNew()...
.catch( function ( error ) {
    ....
} );
```

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery 3.x comes with a Promises/A+ compliant `then` and `catch` method. Why would you still try to make your own??

Comment: I don't use jQuery 3.x. I use version 1.12.4. Otherwise the reason is that I 'd like to use more than one promise providers. I'd like to use similar methods for all of them creathing the ObjectPromise wrapper.

Comment: I think it is a bad design choice to stick with jQuery 1.x (which is end of life) and prefer to make your own implementation, than to rely on a proven implementation which is available just by including jQuery 3.x. You could also include a library like BlueBird. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I need to support older browsers like IE 8. jQuery 3+ supports IE 9+.

Comment: Then bluebird is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I used to include q promises, but as I found out, they didn't always work well on older browsers. I looked at the documentation of BlueBird. It says that it supports older browsers. I hope it is so. I'll test it later.